# Are there any special considerations for installing laminate on a 2nd floor?

Tags: flooring, subfloor, laminate-floor

I have installed a lot of laminate in 1st floor rooms, with concrete subfloors. No issues there. Now I'm installing in a second floor bedroom in a townhouse. Before I rip up carpet Im checking to see if there are any special considerations to consider for 2nd floor installations.

I know this question is a little broad so I'm up for edits to make more specific.

Comment: Well, the second floor probably won't have concrete subfloors. Outside of that, I'm not sure why you think there might be special considerations.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about the issues with noise ( is a thicker sound barrier required) should a moisture block still be used? But idk if it's that similar then I guess I'm all good?

Comment: Moisture block isn't needed since moisture shouldn't be present. I'm not sure why a sound barrier would be needed in either case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a high rated sound barrier to cancel noise.

Comment: Could I use 2 layers?